# Setting all values of an Flag enum except of one field

Tags: c#, enums, bit, enum-flags

I've got the following declaration

```
 private uint mask;
 Action<FlagEnum> setField = new Action<FlagEnum>(x => this.mask = (uint)x);
```

and the following enum for example:

```
[Flags]
public enum FlagEnum : uint
{
    Clear = 0x0,
    F1 = 0x1,
    F2 = F1 << 1,
    F3 = F2 << 1,
    F4 = F3 << 1,
    F5 = F4 << 1,
    F6 = F5 << 1
}
```

Now i want to set all flags except of the 'Clear' flag. I've tried this:

```
 setField(!FlagEnum.Clear);
```

But i get the following message

```
Operator '!' cannot be applied to perand of type 'BitMask.FlagEnum'
```

Setting a flag with, for example:

```
 setField(FlagEnum.F1)
```

Works fine.

So the question is how can i set all fields of the FlagEnum instead of the 'Clear' one with my approach? Or is this not possible and i have to implement this requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your particular case, `FlagEnum.Clear` is set to zero, which means it cannot be "set". Your flags are defined as follows (shortened to 8 bits):

```
Clear = 00000000
F1    = 00000001
F2    = 00000010
F3    = 00000100
F4    = 00001000
F5    = 00010000
F6    = 00100000
```

So, if, say, `F2`, `F3` and `F5` are combined, the binary representation of your value would be `00010110` - it's the combination obtained from a bitwise OR of those three flags.

However, how is `Clear` supposed to be added there? `Clear` is zero, so ORing it to the value will not change anything. Instead, only if none of the other flags is set, your value is automatically `Clear`.

If this is not whant you intended, start with assigning `0x01` to `Clear`.

---

Generally, you can indeed remove a single value from your flags variable, and your idea about negating the flag's value was correct - just that in C#, the bitwise NOT is expressed by a tilde (`~`) rather than the exclamation mark used for a logical not.

So, the inverted bit pattern of `F2` is `11111101`. To remove `F2` from `00010110`, an OR will not do, because the result would be `11111111`. Instead, the negated value has to be ANDed with the previous flags combination:

```
00010110 & 11111101 = 00010100 (F3, F5)
```

Comment: Thanks for that round up. So far my implementation works well. I have the OR, AND & XOR operation. Now what `setField(!FlagEnum.Clear);` should do is just set all bits from 0 to 1 and let the 1 unchanged. Like a method called `FillField()` **bold** okay i found it:  `this.mask = ~(uint)FlagEnum.Clear`did the trick

Comment: @DanielW.: Personally, I'd consider adding another constant to your `enum` that explicitly ORs all defined values to be cleaner, but of course it requires a few more lines of coding. Anyway, please select the answer as selected if it helped you, or otherwise feel free to enquire further.

Answer (score 0):

Following O.R. Mapper approach i've resolved it that way:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Operates the specified flag.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="flag">The flag.</param>
    /// <param name="operation">The operation.</param>
    public void Operate(FlagEnum flag, OperationEnum operation)
    {
        this.flag = flag;
        switch (operation)
        {
            case OperationEnum.AND:
                operate((x, y) => x & y);
                break;
            case OperationEnum.OR:
                operate((x, y) => x | y);
                break;
            case OperationEnum.XOR:
                operate((x, y) => x ^ y);
                break;
            case OperationEnum.NOT:
                throw new NotImplementedException("The operation 'NOT' is not implemented so far!");
        }
    }

 /// <summary>
    /// Operates the specified operation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="operation">The operation.</param>
    private void operate(Func<uint, uint, uint> operation)
    {
        this.Mask = operation(this.Mask, (uint)this.flag);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears the mask.
    /// </summary>
    public void ClearMask()
    {
        this.Mask = (uint)FlagEnum.Clear;
    }
```